# Format Cell Phone number on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I searched for a formula to format 10 digit cell phone number on Crystal reports.The output should be this type-(856)854-8098.The formula was:
Picture(ToText({Command.Cell Phone},**"##########"**),"(xxx) xxx-xxxx")

When I applied it on my report it gave an error on the highlighted part saying "Too many arguments have been given to this function"
Please suggest,how should I modify it to work properly.

Comment: Can you post how your data looks like

Answer (score 0):

I copied your original formula to my report and substituted your command field with a formula containing the phone number you provided.  I was able to add it to the report just fine.  One debugging option is to hardcode the phone number into a formula on your end and then substitute `{Command.CellPhone}` with the formula and retest.

I was also able to get it to work by placing this in a formula:

```
Picture(ToText({@phonenum},"0",0),"(xxx) xxx-xxxx")
```

Lastly, a dirtier alternative is to place the following in a formula:

```
'(' & mid(totext({@phonenumber},"0",0),1,3) & ')' & ' ' & Mid(totext({@phonenumber},"0",0),4,3) & '-' & Mid(totext({@phonenumber},"0",0),7,4)
```

Note:

- This solution assumes that the cellphone number field will always be 10   digits
- Replace {@phonenumber} with your phone number field from the report Command.

Comment: Thanx Robert.I would definitely make it work & let you know.

Comment: Robert,I did tried using your formula and unfortunately,I am still getting the same error.I am using Crystal reports 11.I even made another formula for ToText() but I am getting same error there too.Please suggest.

Comment: The cell phone field on my report is of String type.Is this causing any error?

Comment: Actually, perhaps!  Since it is already a string, you should be able to remove `ToText()` from your formula.  I would try that next and see if it works.  i.e. `Picture({Command.CellPhone},"(xxx) xxx-xxxx")`

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.